# Matlab 2019b installation issue

Tags: 19.04, matlab

I installed Matlab 2019b and in the terminal it says finished, but when I try to run Matlab it's not there and when I press super and search for matlab there's nothing!

Answer (score 0):

The `matlab` executable should be located at:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019b/bin/matlab
```